# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type ammo counter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a VR game where I want to display the ammo next to the gun. I keep getting a error and dont know how to fix it. Please help

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ammoText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject weapon;

    Text ammoText;

    void Awake()
    {
        ammoText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ammoText.text = weapon.GetComponent<Gun>().currentBullets.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory I'd say ... name the `Text ammoText` something different than the class name `ammoText` ...

Answer (score 1):

After passing line `public class ammoText : MonoBehaviour` the compiler knows that `ammoText` is a class and this is used to evaluate the correctness of the code. Statement `Text ammoText;` generates a compilation error because class `ammoText` must not occur in such a statement. Also other occurrences of `ammoText` will generate errors.

It is recommended to start class names with capital letters so it may be enough to rename the class to `AmmoText`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't name a variable the same as your class name. Change the text field name from `ammoText` to something else.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ammoText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject weapon;

    Text renameThis;

    void Awake()
    {
        renameThis = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        renameThis.text = weapon.GetComponent<Gun>().currentBullets.ToString();
    }
}
```